# Apache2 2.2.14 setup with multiple virtual hosts for local testing

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have setup an Apache 2 virtual host by this method.

under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` I've create a `dummy_site_1.conf`

## dummy_site_1.conf

```
<VirtualHost local.dummy_site_1:80>
    ServerName local.dummy_site_1
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dummy_site_1
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dummy_site_1__error.log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/dummy_site_1__access.log
    <Directory /var/www/dummy_site_1>
        AllowOverride Options Limit None
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    #DISABLE HTTP TRACE
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    #RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added this line the the `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerName local.dummy_site_1
```

Now all is working with this setup, I type `local.dummy_site_1` in the URL and I can see my site.

The problem is when I try to add another site config `dummy_site_2.conf` and create about the same settings

## dummy_site_2.conf

```
<VirtualHost local.dummy_site_2:80>
    ServerName local.dummy_site_2
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dummy_site_2
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dummy_site_2__error.log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/dummy_site_2__access.log
    <Directory /var/www/dummy_site_2>
        AllowOverride Options Limit None
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    #DISABLE HTTP TRACE
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    #RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added this line the the `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerName local.dummy_site_2
```

I get this error:

```
user@host:/etc/apache2$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                     [Wed Sep 15 14:00:43 2010] [error] (EAI 5)No address associated with hostname: Could not resolve host name local.dummy_site_2 -- ignoring!
 ... waiting [Wed Sep 15 14:00:44 2010] [error] (EAI 5)No address associated with hostname: Could not resolve host name local.dummy_site_2 -- ignoring!
```

Why? am I configuring this wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need '`ServerName local.dummy_site_2`' in httpd.conf so take that out, but add this instead:

```
NameVirtualHost ip-address-of-server:80
```

eg: NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80

Once you have made the change you will need to restart Apache.

If things still do not work as expected, add a line to each of your virtualhost conf files below the servername lines so they look like this:

```
ServerName local.dummy_site_1
ServerAlias *.local.dummy_site_1 local.dummy_site_1
```

and

```
ServerName local.dummy_site_2
ServerAlias *.local.dummy_site_2 local.dummy_site_2
```

Again, restart Apache to check out the changes.

EDIT: Silly me - just spotted the other bit of the problem - ALL of your VirtualHost declarations should use the IP address of the virtual server - eg:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did step on and got an error. Did step 2 and same error as well as the original error: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Comment: I'm using a static IP if that matters

Comment: Hmm - not sure about the error if you put the NameVirtualHost line in - I just checked one of our servers that is hosting 8 virtual sites and the syntax checks out. The message about the fully qualified domain name should not stop things working, but check that /etc/hosts has a line for 127.0.0.1 listing the names for your server eg: mine is 127.0.0.1 rusty.localdomain rusty localhost.localdomain localhost

Comment: See my edit to my original reply - just spotted the final bit of the jigsaw!

Comment: hmm, that gave the same error as well, also when I hit the first site it comes up with the It works message from Apache instead

Comment: Hmm I think it's has to do with /etc/hosts I didn't add the second domain but when I did it points to the first domain. any thoughts?

Comment: Darn! File permissions OK? Anything in the logs?

Comment: Hmm I think it's has to do with /etc/hosts I didn't add the second domain but when I did it points to the first domain. any thoughts?

Comment: VirtualHost local.dummy_site_1:80 overlaps with VirtualHost local.dummy_site_2:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive

Comment: OK - stick both virtual host definitions in the one .conf file, remove the NameVirtualHost definition from httpd.conf and stick it at the top of the new single .conf file. That at least will make editing easier!

Comment: If you have NameVirtualHost in place AND your virtualhost block definitions use the same IP address as NameVirtualHost you should not be getting the overlap error

Comment: I have just found a note related to the BindAddress setting. I have never set this on my servers but it may be relevant for yours?

Comment: I think placing them in all one config file is working but still testing this. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can remove the IP address and or site name altogether.

example:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin emailaddress@domain.tld
DocumentRoot "/path/to/vhost/documents"
ServerName servername.domain.tld
ServerAlias serveralias.domain.tld
ErrorLog "/path/to/logfiles/servername.domain.tld-error.log"
CustomLog "/path/to/logfiles/servername.domain.tld-access.log" common
<Directory "/path/to/vhost/documents">
allow from all
Option +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin emailaddress@domain.tld
DocumentRoot "/path/to/vhost/documents"
ServerName servername.domain.tld
ServerAlias serveralias.domain.tld
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate/file.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/certificate/file.key
ErrorLog "/path/to/logfiles/servername.domain.tld-error.log"
CustomLog "/path/to/logfiles/servername.domain.tld-access.log" common
<Directory "/path/to/vhost/documents">
allow from all
Option +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(Now, lets do an example of vhost combined with mod_proxy; ip=numeric-octet, below)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://ip.ip.ip.ip/
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip.ip.ip.ip/
ServerName servername.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, so long as your DNS info matches up with the vhosts you configure, then it should all work.